# Trouble with os.path() in python

Tags: python, macos, core-graphics, pyobjc

I have a MacOS PyObjC script that gets the filename of a PDF and adds this as the Title metadata to the PDF itself.

I use a key/variable pair of `kCGPDFContextTitle` and `title`, which goes into a dictionary of metadata.

If I define `title` as the entire filepath, taken from `sys.argv`, then the value correctly appears in the PDF's metadata.

If I define `title` as a given string, it works.

If I define `title` as `os.path.basename(filename)`, then it does not appear in the metadata.

Spaces in the filename are not a factor. The relevant code is:

```
def setMetadata(filename):
    options = {}    
    title = os.path.basename(filename)  
    titleKey = Quartz.kCGPDFContextTitle

    pdfURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath_(filename)
    pdfDoc = Quartz.PDFDocument.alloc().initWithURL_(pdfURL)

    options[titleKey] = title
    pdfDoc.writeToFile_withOptions_(filename, options)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
        setMetadata(filename)
```

If I `print()` the `options` dictionary, I can see no structural difference between the working data and the non-working data. The type is string. Other Key/pairs are included, and appear in the metadata without issue.

Comment: how do you call your script with params?

Comment: `metadata.py filename1 filename2 ....`

Comment: full filenames? like `'/bin/user/whatever/myomy.pdf'` ? or just `python metadata.py one.pdf two.pdf` .. if the latter, try changing to `python metadata.py ./one.pdf ./two.pdf`

Comment: Yes. As said, the full path will appear in the metadata. But if I split it to just get the filename without the path, it doesn't work.

Comment: No, I'm using full paths: either by dragging files into the Terminal window from the Finder, or by using the script in an Automator "Run Shell Script" action. I get identical results in each. If I don't use os.path, I get the full path in the PDF metadata. If I do, I get nothing. I've confirmed that the split pathname is actually in the dictionary.

Comment: Weird. `options[titleKey] = "not a path"` works to give it this title? No clue - luck getting one here

Comment: Yes, that works. It's possibly a bug in the PDFKit API, but I can't see how it differentiates.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, this was fixed with further text processing.

Using the `capitalize()` method on the end of the string declaration worked.

```
title = os.path.basename(filename).capitalize()
```

Alternatively, I could also get the same result by removing the file ending with `os.path.splitext()` after declaring `title`.

```
title = os.path.basename(filename)
title = os.path.splitext(title)[0]
```

No idea what was wrong with the original string, but the Gods of CoreGraphics are now satisfied.